# Homeomorphic products of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be topological spaces such that $X$ and $Y$ are NOT homeomorphic. Is it possible that the product spaces $X \times Z$ and $Y \times Z$ are homeomorphic?
I tried to prove that this is impossible, by constructing a homeomorphism from $X$ to $Y$ using the existing homeomorphism from $X \times Z$ to $Y \times Z$, but I didn't manage to. Is there maybe a counterexample? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are indeed counterexamples: $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}\cong \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}\times \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$

Comment: Or $X=[0,1), Y=[0,1], Z=[0,1)$ for finite and positive dimensional examples. Or $\{0,1\} \times C \cong C \times C$, where $C$ is the Cantor set, for zero-dimensional ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you restrict yourself to the case of finite-dimensional CW complexes (or even manifolds without boundary) surprisigly you can construct meaningful counterexamples without point-set-topology issues. There are several pairs of smooth manifolds which are not even homotopy equivalent, but become diffeomorphic after taking a product with a sphere. See: Hilton, Mislin, Roitberg.  Sphere bundles over spheres and non-cancellation phenomena.